# ArcGIS Server License Update - Additional steps for Enterprise GeoDatabase?

Tags: arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, license

I've already posted more or less the [same question at esri's GeoNet Forum](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/166091), but until now I have got any response. As my license will expire shortly, the is my second try to get some information before license-expiration.
Last year, I have struggled with the some problems with my enterprise geodatabase after my license expired.

My environment is the following:

- Windows Server 2012
- ArcGIS Server 10.3.1
- GeoEvent Processor 10.3.1
- Enterprise Geodatabase (postgreSQL) on the same machine as ArcGIS
  Server/GeoEvent Extension

My current licenses will expire after the 29th of September (so in 1,5 hours) but I have already a new license-file for the next year.
For the license-update process, I would perform the following steps:
Using the license-file and the ArcGIS Administrator I'll authorize my ArcGIS Server instance including the GeoEvent Processor.

To avoid problems with my enterprise geodatabase: Are there any additional steps, which I have to perform (like inject the license key directly in my database)?!
And what's about my GeoDatabase-Connection from my personal computer to the enterprise geodatabase? Do I have to establish a new connection using a "new generated" keycodes file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally I've updated my ArcGIS Server instance (including GeoEvent Extension and Enterprise GeoDatabase) to the new license successfully.
Find below my performed steps to complete the update-process:

1. Update your ArcGIS Server license (and extensions) by double-clicking on the license file, which will start the Software-Authorization wizard. Optionally you can start the Software-Authorization Wizard and manually by navigating to the following folder: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\`, start the `SoftwareAuthorization.exe` and browse to your new license file.
2. Follow the needed steps (like providing contact information, selecting the extension, you want to authorize)
3. Wait for the success-message.
4. Restart your Server (maybe it is sufficient to start/stop/restart the ArcGIS Server process via [services.msc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755249.aspx))
5. Start ArcCatalog and use the DataBase-connection, which was used to create your Enterprise Geodatabase (in my case it was the sde-user, which is created by default). Double-Click the DataBase-Connection.
6. Using the opened wizard, browse to the keycodes-file, which will contain the updated license-information. The keycodes-file is located in the following location:
   `C:\Program Files\ESRI\License10.3\sysgen` on your ArcGIS Server Host. 
   [image: Update license for enterprise geodatabase]
7. Wait some seconds and voilà: License-Update should be completed.
8. Restart the ArcGIS-Server Services (for instance using the ArcGIS-Server Manager), which are based on or use your Enterprise Geodatabase.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update the license *before* expiry, you can use the "Update Enterprise Geodatabase License" toolbox tool available in ArcMap, ArcCatalog or Pro.

1. Install new license on the ArcGIS server, using the Software-Authorization Wizard
2. Copy the `keycodes` file from your ArcGIS Server machine (C:\Program Files\ESRI\License10.x\sysgen\keycodes) to wherever you have access to it in ArcMap/ArcCatalog/Pro. You can inspect this file with a text editor or hexeditor, the newly applied license expiry dates should be found in there.
3. Have a SDE connection file to your database that uses the SDE db's owner as the login (default `sde`).
4. Start the license update tool found in the ArcMap/ArcCatalog/Pro Toolbox at Data Management Tools - Geodatabase Administration - Update Enterprise Geodatabase License
5. Fill the fields with a) the SDE connection file path, b) the keycodes file path, run the tool

You can check if the upgrade was successful by querying your database, e.g. for an MSSQL installation:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [my_egdb].[sde].[SDE_server_config]
  WHERE prop_name = 'AUTH_KEY'
```

The `char_prop_value` should contain the new expiry date (`...;1-mar-2022;...`).